# MatLAB SQLite doesn't read NaN values if first in a column of a table

Tags: matlab, sqlite

I've got a problem with a database created with matlab sqlite.
I create the database with a table inside it using sqlwrite, all good.
When i try to fetch the table, it gives me an error only when a NaN value is in the first index of the column. If a NaN value is not the first index, it doesn't give me any error.

```
dati_Osp = readtable("OSPEDALE1_Reg2.xls");
dati_Osp = renamevars(dati_Osp, 1:width(dati_Osp), ["ANNO", "AZIENDA", "ISTITUTO", "DISCIPLINA_DIMISSIONE", "PROGRESSIVO_REPARTO", "REGIME_DI_RICOVERO", "PROVENIENZA", "DRG", "GIORNATE_DEGENZA", "ACCESSI_IN_DH", "IMPORTO_REGIONALE", "DATA_DIMISSIONE", "COMUNE_DI_RESIDENZA", "ETA", "SESSO", "DIAGNOSI_PRINCIPALE", "DIAGNOSI_CONCOMITANTE1", "DIAGNOSI_CONCOMITANTE2", "DIAGNOSI_CONCOMITANTE3", "DIAGNOSI_CONCOMITANTE4", "INTERVENTO_PRINCIPALE", "INTERVENTO_SECONDARIO1", "INTERVENTO_SECONDARIO2", "INTERVENTO_SECONDARIO3", "INTERVENTO_SECONDARIO4", "MODALITA_DI_ACCESSO", "MODALITA_DI_DIMISSIONE", "TIPO_DI_RICOVERO", "DATA_INGRESSO", "TIPO_PRESCRITTORE", "CODICE_NOSOLOGICO"]);
dati_Osp(:, [28, 30]) = [];


%creazione DB
%conn_Osp = sqlite("DB_Osp", "create"); %eseguire solo la prima volta per creare il database
conn_Osp = sqlite("DB_Osp"); %da eseguire dalla seconda volta in poi
sqlwrite(conn_Osp, "dati_Osp", dati_Osp);
```

This is what i've done.
Mind that, for instance, the column called GIORNATE_DEGENZA has NaN values, just not in the first index and when i do *fetch(conn_Osp, 'SELECT GIORNATE_DEGENZA FROM dati_Osp)* it prints me the correct column with NaN values in it. Otherwise, ACCESSI_IN_DH has a NaN value as the first index and i gives me this error:

```
>> fetch(conn_Osp, 'SELECT ACCESSI_IN_DH FROM dati_Osp')
Error using matlab.depfun.internal.database.SqlDbConnector/fetchRows
Unexpected NULL; (zero-based) column index: 0. Details: [initVecVarVecFromSqldbTypes].

Error in sqlite/fetchHook

Error in database.relational.connection/fetch (line 234)
        data = fetchHook(connect,second_input,optsObject,isDynamicQuery,dynamicQuery,maxRows,preserveNames,dataReturnFormat,nvPairs{:});
```

ADDING
I'm adding a part which was suggested in the comments:

conn = sqlite("DBPROVA", 'create');

T = readtable("pratica.txt");

sqlwrite(conn, "pratica", T);

fetch(conn,'select * from pratica')

close(conn)

the file is this: (pratica.txt)

PRATICA GIORNI_DEGENZA  COD_REP DRG IMPORTO
2003003986  103 NaN 297 10814
2003004403  78  NaN 462 8490
2003004467  69  7501    012 20941
2003004529  65  7501    012 20173
2003004716  55  3203    014 6289
2003004873  47  NaN 012 15049
2003004980  34  7501    012 10887
2003005005  41  7501    012 13128
2003005050  42  7501    013 13448

just copy and paste this and save it as "pratica.txt", it gives the same exact error and i don't know what to do

Comment: This would be a great [mre] if instead of reading from an excel file we don't have access to, it'd create the data explicitly. That way we can copy-paste the code and see what you see, and experiment with it to figure out what is going on. If this is, as it seems, an actual bug, you should report it to the MathWorks.

Comment: I've tried but it gives the same results, i actually hope it's not a bug

Comment: “I've tried but it gives the same results” — Exactly, that’s the point. Please [edit] that into your post instead of the code that reads the excel file. Then we can run the code and see what you are seeing.

Comment: @CrisLuengo i've added the part without the excel file, really appreciated if you could give it a go